# Is the exponential of the distribution $i\Delta^+(x)$, the 2-point function of a free quantized Klein-Gordon field theory, a distribution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

From answers to [a previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/is-a-normal-ordered-product-of-free-fields-at-a-point-a-wightman-field), a finite degree polynomial in the distribution $i\Delta^+(x)$, with Fourier transform $2\pi\delta(k^2-m^2)\theta(k_0)$, *is* a distribution, even though a product of distributions is not in general well-defined. So far I've not been able to find, or be myself sure enough, whether $\exp{\!\left(i\Delta^+(x)\right)}$ is a distribution. It seems that the exponential is the boundary value of the function $\exp{\!\left(\frac{1}{z^2-m^2}\right)}$, but it's not clear to me yet whether that's enough. There seems to be nothing on this in Streater & Wightman (which I own, but don't yet understand well enough to apply the methods), and I don't have heavy lifting books like Reed & Simon, etc.

More specifically, what I currently think I'm *really* interested in is whether a bounded function of a distribution, such as $\tan{\!{}^{-1}\left(\exp{\left(i\Delta(x)\right)}\right)}$, is a distribution.

Comment: I'm thinking this would be more appropriate for Math Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for that, Keenan. I thought of going to Math Overflow, but I don't currently have an account.

Comment: I've toyed with offering a bounty on this, but two days later it seems that this is not the right place to start from. I take the lack of attempts to answer the question to be a reflection of that (I'm checking off Roy's offering, though it's clearly not an *answer*, as an indirect way to kill the question). Math Overflow now seems clearly not appropriate for the question as asked here. In any case, I know precisely how I'll regularize in the construction I'm developing, but it goes against a few prejudices, so it needs a lot of explanation, which is never good in a paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter,

Since your original post on this topic I have encountered "Causal Perturbation Theory" which does distribution-like calculations using a modification of distributions based on Scaled Test Functions. This paper does lots of interaction and S matrix calculations. Perhaps you are entirely familiar with this, or it is not suitable but here is the link I have been studying:

http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/hep-th/pdf/9710/9710225v1.pdf

Comment: Interesting, relatively nice Mathematics, and I think I hadn't seen it before. http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2252, which I had seen before, cites the paper you're looking at. In these terms, $\exp{(i\Delta^+(x))}$ has infinite scaling degree, so I think it's outside. I feel quite disaffected with multinomial expansions in terms of multiplication and derivation operators, since convergence of polynomial expansions to analytic functions is almost always restricted to a (commonly *very*) limited domain. Thanks, Roy.